# Owin and Windows Auth (mvc5) - using Windows auth as a part of login

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm trying to have a MVC5 webapp which *partially* uses Windows Auth.

What I mean by that is, it's effectively forms/cookie based auth, but with the requesting user's Windows principal forming a *part* of their login credentials.

For example, the login page will say, "You have been identified as **somedomain\kierenj**.  Please enter the secret code to log in."  If they enter the correct code, the cookie is set and they're logged in.

If Windows auth fails, then the login page would still appear, but be disabled.

I've experimented with a WindowsPrincipalHanlder like this: https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR/blob/master/JabbR/Middleware/WindowsPrincipalHandler.cs

The gist of it is, if I enable Windows Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication, then Owin (or presumably the cookie auth part of it) redirects to the login page - which redirects to the login page - it's a redirect loop.

Note I'm using a very simplified Owin setup.  `UseCookieAuthentication` with `ApplicationCookie` type and a `LoginPath` specified; then I call `SignIn` like this from my account controller:

```
        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Username"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "AuthenticatedUser")
        };
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie));
```

(Having first checked `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` for example)

Do I really need to write my own version of the Owin cookie auth middleware?  Can I get the source so I can debug/derive?

Comment: were you ever able to figure out an answer to this question?

Comment: Does this - https://github.com/MohammadYounes/MVC5-MixedAuth/tree/Update3 - help?

Answer (score -2):

To avoid the redirect loop, in the constructor of the controller that serves the Login page, try setting current HttpContext's Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect to `true`

Comment: This doesn't help at all